# int error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, arrays, exception

When I run this code, I get the following error: "int error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".

Would anyone be able to explain to me why this happens?

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Eleven
{
    static void name(int n)
    {
        int f1 = 0, f2 = 1, i;
        int next;
        String []arr= new String[1000000000];

        if (n < 1)
            return;

        for (i = 1; i <= n+1; i++)
        {

            next = f1 + f2;
            arr[next]="O";
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = next;
        }
         for (i = 1; i <= n+1; i++)
         {
             if(arr[i]!="O")
                 arr[i]="o";
         }
         for (i = 1; i <= n+1; i++)
         {
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
         }
    }    


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n;
        System.out.println("enter the lenth of name");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
        n=sc.nextInt();
        name(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: Really? `new String[1000000000]`? That requires 4GB just for the empty array. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: `String []arr= new String[1000000000];` do you really need an array that big?

Comment: arr[10000] was just for testing i took arr[1000]

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure you are using a 64 bit JVM.

Second, add memory to the JVM with this arguments:
-Xms512m -Xmx4g